# Algolia Search Network Error

Tags: javascript, firebase, runtime-error, algolia

I'm connecting Algolia with a Firebase project I have. I'm using the Firebase Cloud Functions in order to keep my Algolia index synced with all changes that occur in my Firebase database. But whenever I call

index.saveObject(firebaseObject);

from inside my Firebase Cloud Functions, I get

AlgoliaSearchNetworkError: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND 5sffby8as8-1.algolianet.com 5sffby8as8-1.algolianet.com:443

I can run the syncing operation just fine outside of Firebase Functions (just on my own machine). This code is run in a javascript file through node.js.

I haven't found any current questions or answers about this in any of my searches. Any ideas or help?

Answer (score 30):

I found out that the Spark plan on Firebase (the free-tier that I was using) doesn't allow outbound requests to 3rd-party APIs. I had to upgrade to one of the paid plans (Flame or Blaze) to be able to connect to the Algolia network from within the Firebase Cloud Functions.

A caveat was included in their [getting started guide](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/get-started).

Comment: For reference to anyone reading this, the Blaze plan is pretty much free. It's pay-as-you-go, but at the bottom of the Firebase Pricing page you can see that most things come free with it. This includes 5GB of 3rd-party API data transfer in Cloud Functions for free.